# Module is not recognized in an environment where TensorFlow recognizes GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm in Windows 11 environment now, and I downloaded the TensorFlow GPU that can be accelerated using wsl according to the official document

And I'm using Jupiter's laptop in that environment

Sometimes it doesn't recognize GPUs, sometimes it does, but the problem is that when it does, only tensorflow works and the rest of the modules don't recognize numpy, sklearn, and matplotlib

You can't download the command from the next shell, you've even installed it in every environment

But it doesn't work only when it's a kernel that recognizes GPUs, any solutions?

I want to use various modules in an environment where TensorFlow recognizes GPU
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynNOo.png)

Comment: Are you running inside WSL in Windows?  I wasn't aware GPUs could be forwarded to WSL.

Comment: Have you installed `sklearn` in your Jupyter environment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.